# What happens if a thread opens a socket and the main program exits?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

What happens if a thread opens a socket and the main program exits? I have seen sometimes that threads will run for a second or two after the main program exits, but will the socket that the thread opened up be closed when the main program exits, or when the thread finally cleans itself up an dies?

Answer (score 7):

When the program (ie. JVM process) stops, all resources are released. If there is a System.exit() call made, then the JVM stops. If on the other hand, your main thread finish execution, the JVM continues to run until there are no more non-daemon threads running. So if the thread that handles the socket communication is a non-daemon thread, it will continue to run.

Answer (score 0):

If the main program ends, the threads would have been killed preliminarily. So they can't run 1 or 2 seconds after the main program ended.

I kindly ask you to read a bit about Interprocess Communication, which is a Standard how processes in a computer system are exchanging information. You should also read about processes and threads. Yours question is showing, that you have not yet an idea about Threads. Here is an entry point to be found: [Java Tutorials - Processes and so on](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html)

But to answer the question, the JVM uses native C or C++ libraries with such functionality you can find in a man-page like this: [man-page socket in Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket). These libs are used to directly interact with the OS.

Opening a socket bound to a java-process means, that the socket will be kept, as long as the parent process runs (from a users view). When now a process is terminated, all threads of this process be ended, too. But not the socket, as this is a separate process in the OS and handled by the OS and JVM. A JVM will care (for you) about to terminate all sockets belonging to the program or process which called to create them. By means, the JVM will automatically call the OS to close the socket (do not rely on it). Otherwise there would be an orphan process as an open socket, which is considered dangerous.

The garbage collection and calling tasks take some time. Hope this helps a bit.